# Find strings starting with alphanumeric in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to search for all records starting alphabet or number only.

I know there is REGEXP_LIKE to find if col contains alphanumeric but couldn't apply it for starting with.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 like 'ABC:XYZ%'
```

I have data in below format:--

```
ABC:XYZ
ABC:XYZ (ERW)
ABC:XYZ TMN
ABC:XYZ123
ABC:XYZRTY:YER
```

I am trying to get only  below output

```
ABC:XYZ
ABC:XYZ123
ABC:XYZRTY:YER
```

Regards

Comment: It is `'^[A-Za-z]'`

Comment: Your regular expression has a typo.  It should be `'^[A-Za-z]'`.

Comment: I will rephrase my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Sample data up to line #7; query you might be interested in begins at line #8.

```
SQL> with mytable (col1)  as
  2    (select 'ABC:XYZ'        from dual union all
  3     select 'ABC:XYZ (ERW)'  from dual union all
  4     select 'ABC:XYZ TMN'    from dual union all
  5     select 'ABC:XYZ123'     from dual union all
  6     select 'ABC:XZYRTY:YER' from dual
  7    )
  8  select col1
  9  from mytable
 10  where not regexp_like(col1, '[^[:alnum:]:]');

COL1
--------------
ABC:XYZ
ABC:XYZ123
ABC:XZYRTY:YER

SQL>
```